# Isotope works in safari - not Firefox or Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser, jquery-isotope

I am using David Desandro's wonderful Isotope jQuery plugin to display a list of titles and descriptions, with the ability to sort by category or by the first letter of the title. It works flawlessly in Safari, however in both Chrome and Firefox, the content disappears from view when a user attempts to sort.

I've removed the object from the project and it still behaves the same. I've created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the behavior at http://jsfiddle.net/gojukebox/mH9Sd/

Comment: You have pasted so much html and css code that it's extremely difficult to probe; can't you provide a stripped down fiddle that still shows the issue? Or provide a link to your sandbox so one can probe it with Chrome's or Firefox's devtools? Usually, Isotope works on all browsers and devices.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Safari (6.0.2 (8536.26.17)). While I didn't investigate the why, I noted that the width of div.overview becomes zero after the first sort - here's a quick CSS fix for this (added to the bottom of your CSS): http://jsfiddle.net/vJxV2/1/

Comment: I have the opposite behaviour. My latest experiment with isotope worked in Opera, but in Safari none of my images appear at all...